# ASP.net, SQL Server web hosting

Tags: asp.net, hosting

I have developed a website using Visual studio .net and SQL server 2005 express edition. The site is commercial. I have domain and webspace which supports asp.net hosting. Do i need to purchase a license copy of visual studio or SQLserver in order to launch my website? Please help.

Comment: Visual Studio: no, certainly not - that's a **development** tool, you don't need this to run the site. SQL Server: maybe. You can use the **free** Express edition, if that's enough for you - even for commercial sites. If you outgrow the Express edition, then **YES** - you need to purchase a SQL Server license

Comment: Ah - still no. Basically if his webspace provides SQL Server then no. And that is what he says. Plus installing SQL Server on shared webspace is not working anyway. And even then - you do not BUY it, you RENT it via SPLA, Web edition. SQL Server Web edition is surprisingly cheap under SPLA.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in shared hosting the hosting provide will have the license for he asp.net and sql data. So, no need to purchase the license. If you go for dedicated server, then only you want to think of purchasing the license.